# Why is the go compiler saying a struct does not satisfy an interface when it does?

Tags: go

I can see in `scanner.go` that the struct has an `error` method.

```
// A SyntaxError is a description of a JSON syntax error.
type SyntaxError struct {
    msg    string // description of error
    Offset int64  // error occurred after reading Offset bytes
}

func (e *SyntaxError) Error() string { return e.msg }
```

But the compiler tells me this:

`api/errors.go:24: impossible type switch case: err (type error) cannot have dynamic type json.SyntaxError (missing Error method)` when trying to do a switch case on type

```
func myFunction(err error) {
    switch err.(type) {
        case validator.ErrorMap, json.SyntaxError:
        response.WriteErrorString(http.StatusBadRequest, "400: Bad Request")
//etc
```

Why does this not compile?  Because the struct has the `Error` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that `func (e *SyntaxError) Error() string { return e.msg }` is a method for the pointer, whereas I am looking for the method on a value.  I've managed to solve the problem by doing `*json.SyntaxError` to refer to a pointer.